# Projecting on an arbitrary plane

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, projection

I have the following code, giving me a representation of a photon hitting a cylinder:

```
scale1 = 1.2;
scale2 = 2.25;
scale3 = 1.4;
scale4 = 2;
inp = {scale2, scale2, scale2};
intp = {4, 4, 3};
rainp = {4, 0, 0};
raoutp = {4, 8/scale3, 6/scale3};
outp = {4, 4.65, 3.25};
ninra = (intp - inp)\[Cross](raoutp - rainp);
inttan = (raoutp - rainp) - inp;
tandir = (raoutp - rainp)\[Cross] ninra;
tanvect[t_] := inp + t*tandir;
tanvect1 = tanvect[0.15];
v = tandir;
u = raoutp - rainp;
w = rainp - inp;
s = (v[[2]]*w[[1]] - v[[1]]*w[[2]])/(v[[1]]*u[[2]] - v[[2]]*u[[1]]);
t = (u[[1]]*w[[2]] - u[[2]]*w[[1]])/(u[[1]]*v[[2]] - u[[2]]*v[[1]]);
d = EuclideanDistance[inp, tanvect1]*t;
p = tanvect[2*t];

nareaR = ({1, 0, 0}\[Cross]((rainp - raoutp)/Norm[{raoutp - rainp}]));
nareaR = nareaR/Norm[nareaR];

cylinder = 
  ContourPlot3D[y^2 + z^2 == 25, {x, 0, 10}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
  Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Directive[Brown, Opacity[0.25]], 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
areaX = 
  ContourPlot3D[x == 4, {x, 2, 7}, {y, 2, 7}, {z, 0, 5}, 
  Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Directive[White, Dashed, Opacity[0]],
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
areaR = 
  Plot3D[
    (nareaR[[1]]*intp[[1]] + nareaR[[2]]*intp[[2]] + nareaR[[3]]*intp[[3]] -
     nareaR[[1]]*x - nareaR[[2]]*y)/(nareaR[[3]]), 
    {x, 2, 7}, {y, 2, 7}, 
    Mesh -> None,
    PlotStyle -> Directive[White, Dashed, Opacity[0]], 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
axial = 
  Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.02], Black, Dashed, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}}], 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
radius = 
  Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.02], Black, Dashed, Arrow[{rainp, raoutp}], 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
inv = 
  Graphics3D[{Thick, Arrowheads[0.02], Red, Arrow[{inp, intp}], 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
outv = 
  Graphics3D[{Thick, Arrowheads[0.02], Blue, Arrow[{intp, scale1*outp}], 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
reflv = 
  Graphics3D[{Thick, Arrowheads[0.02], Green, Arrow[{{4, 4, 3}, p}], 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
directCos1 = 
  Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.02], Purple, Dashed, Thick, 
    Line[{{4, 4, 3}, {4, scale1*4.65, 3}, {4, scale1*4.65, 3}, 
          {4, scale1*4.65, scale1*3.25}, {4, scale1*4.65, scale1*3.25}, 
          {scale1*4, scale1*4.65, scale1*3.25}}], 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
directCos2 = 
  Graphics3D[{Arrowheads[0.02], Orange, Dashed, Thick, 
    Line[{{scale2*1, scale2*1, scale2*1}, {scale2*1, scale2*1, 3}, 
          {scale2*1, scale2*1, 3}, {scale2*1, 4, 3}, {scale2*1, 4, 3}, 
          {4, 4, 3}}], 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
directCosReflv = 
  Graphics3D[{
    Arrowheads[0.02], Cyan, Dashed, Thick, 
    Line[{{4, 4, 3}, {4, p[[2]], 3}, {4, p[[2]], 3}, 
          {p[[1]], p[[2]], 3}, {p[[1]], p[[2]], 3}, {p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]]}}], 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}}];
Show[
  directCos1, directCos2, directCosReflv, radius, outv, axial, 
   inv, reflv, areaR, areaX, cylinder, 
  Axes -> False, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  Boxed -> False]
```

By setting the viewpoint option in `Show` to be:

```
ViewPoint -> {∞, 0, 0}
```

I get a nice representation in the y,z plane.

My question is how do I easily project the cylinder and its vectors onto the r,x plane?

Comment: What is r x plane?

Comment: In my problem the rx-plane is given by:

x: the axial direction of the cylinder

r: the radius of the cylinder

intp: the vector where the photon strikes the boundary

areaR defines the rx-plane which is of interest for my problem. The question is how to project the whole 3D Graphics onto the areaR plane.

Comment: Notice, that 90% of your code is not important in context of the question. Next time, please, post the minimal example of self consistent code. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see projection on `r-x` plane you can set:

```
ViewPoint - > 1000 Cross[x,r]
```

with assumption that `x` and `r` are not parallel. `Cross` by definition gives you vector normal to the plain stretched by `x` and `r` and `1000` is close enough to `Inf`.

It is really annoying that `r` is not connected with your code and the point we must know is called `intp`...

Projection is set, now you may want to set it straight, use `ViewVertical`:

```
Show[directCos1, directCos2, directCosReflv, radius, outv, axial, inv, 
     reflv, areaR, areaX, cylinder, Axes -> False, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
     Boxed -> False, 
     ViewPoint -> 1000 Cross[{1, 0, 0}, intp], ViewVertical -> {0, 1, 0}]
```

[image]

Comment: I wasn't aware of 
    ViewVertical
Thanks!

Comment: @user8698 You are welcome, but it is only an improvement, projection is done be `ViewPoint`.

Comment: I know, I used `ViewPoint` already with the normal vector of areaR but `ViewPoint` was missing to get the plot I wanted!
Thank you once more!